# How to derive weak solution formulation when $f\in H^{-1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Considering the simplest boundary value problem.
$$\Delta u=f,\text{in}\,\Omega.$$
$$u=0,\text{in}\,\partial\Omega.$$

In evans we always assume $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$ and use integral by parts to $v\Delta u=fv$ where $v$ is a test function.

My question is,how to derive the weak solution formula when $f\in H^{-1}$?

I know the right hand side should be understood as $\langle f,v\rangle=\int f^{0}v+\sum f^{i}v_{x^{i}}.$

But how can I understand the left hand side $\langle\Delta u,v\rangle$?In order to integrate by part it must just be the integral $\int \Delta u v$.But I cannot see why.

Comment: Well, the "integration by parts" for the term $v\Delta u$ works independent of $f$. Or can you elaborate why the RHS should matter?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven How can we use integration by parts when the pair $\langle \Delta u,v\rangle$ is not $\int v\Delta u$?I think this is only valid when $\Delta u\in L^{2}$,which implies $f\in L^{2}$

Comment: The "integration by parts" is not at all an integration by parts. It is just a definition of how $\Delta u$ acts on test functions.

Comment: You need to think of $\Delta u$ as a distribution. Then you have an equation of distributions. Of course the solution will no longer need to be given in term of a function. If you assume that $\Delta u$ is $L^2$, then you force $f$ to be given by a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $f \in H^{-1}$ means that $f$ is in the dual space of $H_0^1$, i.e., $f$ is a linear mapping of $v \in H_0^1$ to (in this context most likely) $\mathbb R$. Thus, it might make more sense to write in this case $f(v)$.

So the space from which $v$ stems is in this case already fixed to $H^1_0$. While you are in theory still free to choose the space $U$ for $u \in U$, it makes most sense to pick the same as for $v$, as then the standard theory (Lax-Milgram, error-estimates, ...) applies. Otherwise, you have to start figuring out stuff on your known, based on how the spaces $H^1_0$ and $U$ are related to one another.

For $u \in H^1_0$, you then obtain the standard LHS

$$ \int_\Omega \Delta u v \mathrm d x = \int_\Omega \nabla \cdot (v \nabla u) - \nabla v \cdot \nabla u \mathrm d x \overset{\text{Divergence Theorem & B.C.}}{=} -\int_\Omega \nabla v \cdot \nabla u \mathrm d x  $$